# Run command every 3rd time in PHP

Tags: php

I have an application that runs a PHP script which essentially sends an email. 
The problem is that I want the PHP script to send the email every 3rd time that its called by the application. So, it needs to somehow check how many times it has been called and if its the 3rd time (or a multiple of 3), it should proceed and run the "send email" command. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with PHP so I don't really know how to accomplish that.

I was thinking that I could have a text file, e.g. counter.txt . Inside it, I could have a single line with a number (e.g. 1). Everytime the PHP script was ran, it would read the first line, increase it by one, do a division by 3 and if the remainder was 0, it would run the "send email" command. Is there an easier way, or how could I accomplish what I just said?

That's what i have so far:

```
<?php
cd /tmp;
cp ls -t1 | head -1 /etc/asterisk/alarm/latest.txt;
php /etc/asterisk/alarm/alarmparse.php; 
mail -s "Subject" email@adress.com -- -f from@address.com </etc/asterisk/alarm/latest.txt;
?>
```

Here is the use of the script: My home alarm system is connected to my asterisk PBX server, to which it sends alarm codes. It essentially dials a number and gives it some DTMF numbers. The problem is that the alarm system calls my PBX 3 times every time there is an event (e.g. alarm goes off) so I get 3 emails for the same event.

What the script does is to get the latest log file (every time the alarm contacts the PBX, a new txt log file is created with the event code that the alarm sent) from a directory and copy it to a txt file. Then it opens that file with another PHP script which translates the alarm code to text (e.g. 1234 > Zone 4 is alarmed) and then saves it to the original file. Then it proceeds and emails me that txt file.

Comment: if ( $i % 3 == 0)  - modulus

Comment: That text file approach could be one possible solution – although it is extremely prone to race conditions and [TOCTTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problems, so would you need to at least implement proper file locking.

Comment: Why run it 2x and not send the mail? - just curious - @CBroe I agree but only if it's asynchronous - how is it called from the "Application"

Comment: Does it *have to be* exactly every 3rd time?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Yes, exactly every 3rd time.

Comment: Why don't you use a database, like Sqlite?

Comment: @MarkusKottländer Wouldn't that be overkill? I'm looking for the simplest solution possible!

Comment: I don't see an issue with using a text file in this situation. Only the alarm server is calling your PHP, if you can make sure that it is the only thing calling your PHP (i.e you webserver is not live), then go for the text file approach.